# Edit Button on Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationitem

I have a navigation controller in my app and on its root view controller i have an Edit button as the rightBarButtonItem.

I have a second table view which is pushed when a cell is tapped on the root view controller.

The leftBarButtonItem becomes the Back button.

I would like an Edit button as well, where can i put it that would make the most sense? My rightBarButtonItem is a + button, so that rules that out.

I would like to be able to tap a cell and change the cells text.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest thing to do is add a toolbar at the bottom that contains an edit button.

You could also try adding a bar button item with a custom view that contains two UIButtons and set it as the right bar button item of your view controller's navigation item. I haven't actually tried this, so I don't really know if or how well it would work.

Comment: I added a bar item and when clicked, I can log that editing mode is on, but no controls (the minus signs) show up. How would i go about checking this? I have added `setEditing:animated:` but when i try to log the editing bool here it is NO.  Thanks.

Comment: You'll probably get better results asking this as a separate question, but I would check the following: "In editing mode, the cells of the table might show an insertion or deletion control on the left side of each cell and a reordering control on the right side, depending on how the cell is configured. The data source of the table view can selectively exclude cells from editing mode by implementing tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:." Taken from http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006943-CH3-SW20.

Comment: Also make sure everything is connected up in Interface Builder.